# When I write a list to excel all the values comes to the same cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to export a list from a code in Python. The output from the code comes this way:

```
print(mylist)

   Allocation
0  55
1  65
2  23
3  23
4  55
5  36
```

When I write this to excel It messes up and all the numbers comes in the same cell. like this:
[image]

```
55
65
23
23
55
36
```

I am writing the list to excel with this comand:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Comment: Try to use a tab character between your columns instead of space?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned anything about your output, If you simply want to Write the DataFrame data into a Excel then your code will work. Just check the path and Sheet name.

```
import pandas as pd
lis = [55,65,23,23,55,36]
df = pd.DataFrame(lis,columns=['alo'],index=None)
file_loc = r'C:\Users\uib05928\Desktop\New folder (2)\new.xlsx'
df1 = df.to_excel(file_loc)
```

Output - [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified what kind of output you want:

if you want it to be printed in each row you should use extra parameter `index` like so:

```
df.to_excel("test.xlsx",
           index=list(df.index.values))
```

Documentation of method [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to save the excel:

```
# DF TO EXCEL
from pandas import ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
yourdf.to_excel(writer,'Sheet5')
writer.save()
```